# Katalon test cannot make calls to different domains

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I'm experiencing a strange behavior when running automated tests with Katalon studio.

The problem occurs across all browsers.

When running a test all calls going to the first url/domain (e.g. google.com) are fine. All calls going to any other domain fail.

The error in console is: 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

If I open a new tab and try to load any other page I get the same error.

Calling any endpoint on the same domain works fine.

The issue occurs on a specific machine. All works well on 2 other machines.

Comment: Do you use same version of browser and Katalon Studio on all the machines?

Comment: Yes. As an update, Even selenium experiences the same issue

Comment: What is the difference between these machines? Version of OS? Do you mean Selenium as WebDriver or as IDE test cases?

Comment: The machines are identical, same OS(Win 10). Selenium doesn't work either way. Anytime a browser is in automated mode no other domains are reachable.